# If a function is defined by a taylor series, how can you derive its inverse in the form of a taylor series?

Tags: calculus

Say you want to find the inverse of a function, and it's not expressible in terms of known functions, so you want to find the taylor series for that inverse. But, you at least know the taylor series for your original function f(x), defined as $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{g(x,n)h(n)}{n!}$$ and it converges for a sufficient radius.
Since Taylor series stem from derivatives, and there is a theorem called the inverse function theorem that relatives derivatives to a functions' inverse 
$$(f^{-1})'(f(x))=\frac{1}{f'(x)},$$

is there any consequential theorem where you can derive a new Taylor series for the inverse of a function by using the original Taylor series for that original function? 
In other words, $$f^{-1}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{???}{n!}$$

Comment: You've already been told about Lagrangian inversion. There are also a number of algorithms that take the coefficients of a Taylor series and spit out the coefficients of the inverse. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/135860), I implement an algorithm by Thacher, and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/135997) you have an approach based on Carleman matrices.

Comment: See [$\mathbf{\color{#00}{3.6.25}}$ in A & S Table: Series Reversion](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_16.htm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible to find the inverse of a Taylor Series. You can use series reversion. It can be used to find the inverse of Taylor Series given the forward function. Here is a URL: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html

Comment: Okay, thank you for bringing that to my attention. It would be helpful if there was an example because for some reason that summation is unexpectedly of several variables at once, it doesn't look like the end result is a nice Taylor series like I'm looking for. Just to be clear, you're not inverting or undoing the summation operator itself, you're actually defining the inverse of the original function explicitly as a taylor series by using a series reversion?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes I believe the inverse function of a Taylor Series can be strictly defined on series reversion (although tedious, it is the most natural definition in my opinion).

Comment: @DaneJoe. Have a look  at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2360037/inverse-function-for-a-taylor-series/2360186#2360186 for an example.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici The problem is that example doesn't actually give any of the intermediate steps, so it doesn't really help anything. When I look for any examples of how to apply this series reversion theorem, there's literally no results whatsoever on the entire internet, there is only a statement of the start of the theorem with no shown application, nothing more. So I have absolutely no way of verifying if I'm interpreting the process correctly even if I arrive at something correct, because it could just be coincidence.

Comment: @DaneJoe. Apply the method by yourself on something like $y=\sin(x)$ to get the Taylor series for $\sin^{-1}(y)$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici That's the thing, I don't even know if I'm applying the first step correctly. I don't even know what the first step is suppose to be, no one really says what it's suppose to be. There's no intermediate steps that explains how it works, no paper on how it was derived. I can't see any reason why an explicit inverse would suddenly explode with a shotgun of random variables that were never present in the original function. If I start with x, y and n, then I expect to end with x, y and n.

Comment: @DaneJoe. I shall write the example.

Answer (score 2):

Considering $y=\sin(x)$, let us develop it as a truncated Taylor series
$$y=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}+\cdots\tag 1$$ Now, following the steps given [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html), let $$x=a_1y+a_2y^2+a_3y^3+a_4y^4+a_5y^5+\cdots\tag 2$$ and replace.

Expand all terms and group the terms for a given power of $y$. You will get
$$y=a_1 y+a_2 y^2+\left(a_3-\frac{a_1^3}{6}\right) y^3+\left(a_4-\frac{1}{2} a_1^2
   a_2\right) y^4+\frac{1}{120} \left(a_1^5-60 a_3 a_1^2-60 a_2^2 a_1+120
   a_5\right) y^5+\cdots\tag 3$$ Now, identify the powers to get $$a_1=1$$ $$a_2=0$$ $$a_3-\frac{a_1^3}{6}=0\implies a_3=\frac 16 $$ $$a_4-\frac{1}{2} a_1^2
   a_2=0\implies a_4=0$$ $$a_1^5-60 a_3 a_1^2-60 a_2^2 a_1+120
   a_5=0\implies a_5=\frac 3 {40}$$

Comment: I guess it's not too terribly different than the normal process for deriving a Taylor series. I will look at it more in depth tomorrow when I have time, thank you for explaining it I'll get back to you on this.

Comment: @DaneJoe. It is different since the coefficients are no more related to the derivatives. But, as you see, you just need to solve a few equations (one at the time as I did here).

Comment: Alright thanks it works out. It is confusing when WA says "plug in" because that makes it seem literally like every single instance of "x" is replaced with the *entire* infinite series defined by y.