# Multiplying the long polynomials for $e^x$ and $e^y$ does not give me the long polynomial for $e^{x+y}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

As an alternative to normal rules for powers giving $e^xe^y=e^{(x+y)}$ I am multiplying the long polynomial of the taylor series of $e^x$ and $e^y$. I only take the first three terms:
$$ \left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots\right)\left(1+y+\frac{y^2}{2!}+\cdots\right).$$
With this I try to reach 
$$1+(x+y)+\frac{(x+y)^2}{2!}+\cdots$$ 
I collect a lot of terms and take the terms I know to be equal to $(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2$, but I'm then left with terms like $yx^2/2!+xy^2/2!$ These last terms I cant solve away. Am I doing something wrong or can I just say that I'll keep those for the $+\cdots$ bit?

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/405628/28900).

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414061/prove-exy-exey-by-using-exponential-series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those terms belong to the $(x+y)^3$ term. The way to see that is the their total power is 3 a la the binomial theorem. The proper way to do this problem is with [Cauchy products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product).

Comment: thank you, googling cauchy products does look useful

Answer (score 1):

You are doing right.  If you expand $e^{(x+y)}$ you get $1+(x+y)+\frac 12(x+y)^2+\frac 16(x+y)^3 \dots$ as you say.  Expanding the $\frac 16(x+y)^3$ term gives $\frac 16x^3+\frac 12 x^2y+\frac 12xy^2+\frac 16y^3$.  The middle two of these are the ones you are worried about.

Answer (score 0):

$$(1+x+\frac{x^{2}}{2}+...)(1+y+\frac{y^{2}}{2}+...)=1+x+y+\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{y^{2}}{2}+xy+...=$$
$$=1+(x+y)+\frac{(x+y)^{2}}{2}+...$$
The other terms, such as $yx^2/2!+xy^2/2!$ will apear as the parts of the expression $\frac{(x+y)^{3}}{3!}$.

Comment: Thank you, i was wondering how to formalise that

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{y^3}{3!}+\frac{y^2 x}{2!} +\frac{y x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}=\frac{y^3+3y^2x+3yx^2+x^3}{3!}=\frac {(y+x)^3}{3!}$$