# Riemann zeta function - Euler product formula

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta

I want to prove that 
$$ \frac{1}{\zeta(s)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}.$$

I know that the standard proof works with the  Euler product formula $$\zeta(s)=\prod_{p \ \text{prime}} \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}$$ but I am not really used to it (because I don't understand the proof for the Euler product formula). Now I want to know if there is another proof for the identity $\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}$. I thought there might be a method using Möbius inversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\phi$ a multiplicative function and $\phi^*$ its convolutative inverse, that is
$$ \sum\limits_{n|k}  \phi(n) \phi^*(n/k) = \begin{cases} 1, & n=1, \\ 0, & else.\end{cases}$$

Assuming some mild growth condition on $\phi$ and $\phi'$, then we can define
$$Z(\phi,s) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty  \phi(n) n^{-s}$$ and 
$ Z(\phi^*,s)$ analogous for suffienctly large $s \gg 0$ with absolute convergence guaranteed, then for all $s$
$$Z(\phi,s)  Z(\phi^*,s) =1.$$

The idea of proof is
$$ Z(\phi,s)  Z(\phi^*,s)  = \sum_{n,m} \frac{\phi(n) \phi^*(m)}{n^s m^s}$$
and then sum over $k=nm$  first (reorder the sum by absolute convergence).
$$ \dots = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-s} \sum\limits_{n|k}  \phi(n) \phi^*(n/k) = 1.$$
 You get the identity for $s \gg 0$ Then use uniqueness of analytic continuation to make sense for the remaining $s$.

Comment: I would like to have a formal, exact proof - not those dots $\ldots$. Because this is the similar method as with the euler product.

Comment: Use induction... I am not here to do all of your homework;)

Comment: You also need to proof convergence.

Comment: I am not looking for a proof by induction...

Comment: Okay, I got your point.

Answer (score 0):

The following proof of the reciprocal formula for the Riemann Zeta function explains more of the detail and may be helpful. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4571464/417024) to [Euler Product formula for Riemann zeta function proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1742890/417024) may help explain the origin of the Euler product formula.

Assume $\mathrm{Re}(s) > 1$, which ensures the $\zeta$ series is absolutely convergent and the infinite product in Euler's product formula converges, and that $\left| 1 / n^s \right| < 1 / n < 1$ for all $n \geq 2$. Denote by $p_1 < p_2 < \cdots$ the set of all primes. For comparison purposes a heuristic proof is given below also.

## Heuristic Proof

From the Euler product formula we have :
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{\zeta(s)} & = & \prod_{p \text{ prime}} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p^s} \right) \nonumber \\
& = & \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p_1^s} \right) \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p_2^s} \right) \cdots \label{eq:inf-prod} \tag{1}
\end{eqnarray}

Imagine we could treat this infinite product in the same way as a finite product and multiply out the brackets by summing all products $q$ of terms taken one from each bracket in every possible combination (as described at beginning of [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/429963/147246) to [Alternative proofs of Euclid-Euler theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/q/429962/147246)). Then every such product $q$ comprises either finitely or infinitely many $p_r$ terms. In the latter case each term in the product $q$ has modulus of form $1 / p_r^s$. But $\left| 1 / p_r^s \right| < 1 / p_r \leq \frac{1}{2}$, therefore intuitively, as infinitely many such terms are being multiplied, $|q| \leq \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{\infty} = 0$. Thus the overall contribution to the expansion's summation from such products is zero.

Consider now a product $q$ where only finitely many $p_r$'s are involved. Such $q$ has form :
\begin{eqnarray*}
q & = & \frac{{(-1)}^k}{{(q_1 \cdots q_k)}^s} \hspace{2em} \mbox{ where $k \geq 0$ and $q_1, \ldots, q_k$ are distinct primes} \\
& = & \frac{\mu(q_1 \cdots q_k)}{{(q_1 \cdots q_k)}^s}
\end{eqnarray*}

This ranges over all possible selections of distinct primes $q_1, \ldots, q_k$ ($k \geq 0$) due to the infinite product in (\ref{eq:inf-prod}), ie. $q = \mu(n) / n^s$ ranging over all possible *square-free* $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (which includes $1$ when $k = 0$). Then the sum of all these $q$ is :

$$\sum_{\substack{\text{finitely many} \\ p_r \text{'s involved} }} q = \sum_{ \substack{n = 1, \\ n \text{ square-free}} }^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s} $$

since $\mu(n) = 0$ for any non-square-free $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and this is the required formula for $1 / \zeta(s)$.

## Formal Proof

The proposed series is :

\begin{eqnarray}
S & = & \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s} \nonumber \\
& = & \sum_{\substack{n = 1, \\ n \text{ square-free}}}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s} \hspace{3em} (\mbox{since } \mu(n) = 0 \mbox{ for any non-square-free } n \in \mathbb{N}) \label{eq:dirichlet} \tag{2}
\end{eqnarray}

which is the Dirichlet series over the Mobius function (absolutely convergent by comparison with the $\zeta$ series).

From the Euler product formula for $\zeta$, we have :
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{\zeta(s)} & = & \prod_{p \text{ prime}} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p^s} \right) \nonumber \\
& = & \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} Z_m, \hspace{3em} \mbox{where } Z_m = \prod_{r = 1}^m \left(1 - \frac{1}{p_r^s} \right) \label{eq:limZm} \tag{3} \\
\mbox{ie. } Z_m & = & \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p_1^s} \right) \cdots \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p_m^s} \right), \hspace{3em} (2^m \mbox{ terms on multiplying out)} \nonumber \\
\therefore Z_m & = & \sum_{\substack{   k \in \mathbb{N} \text{ square-free}, \\ \text{the primes of } k \\ \subseteq \{p_1, \ldots, p_m \}   }} \frac{\mu(k)}{k^s} \label{eq:Zm} \tag{4}
\end{eqnarray}

since on multiplying out to the $2^m$ terms, we have a summation of all products of terms taken one from each of the $m$ brackets in every possible combination (as described at beginning of [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/429963/147246) to [Alternative proofs of Euclid-Euler theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/q/429962/147246)). Note the summation includes $k = 1$, with the primes of $1$ being the empty set, and the expression for $Z_m$ still makes sense for $m = 0$ where we have :
$$Z_0 = \displaystyle{\prod_{\varnothing}} = \sum_{k \in \{1\}} \mu(k)/k^s = 1.$$

Every $Z_m$ is thus the sum of a finite sub-series of $S$, and the indices in $Z_m$ are enclosed telescopically within each other : $Z_0 \subsetneq Z_1 \subsetneq Z_2 \subsetneq, \cdots$. Now define a sequence of non-overlapping finite sub-series of $S$, $\{S^{(r)} : r \geq 0 \}$ by : $S^{(0)} = Z_0, S^{(1)} = Z_1 \setminus Z_0, S^{(2)} = Z_2 \setminus Z_1, \ldots, S^{(r + 1)} = Z_{r + 1} \setminus Z_r (r \geq 0)$, so :
$$
S^{(m)} = Z_m \setminus Z_{m - 1} = \sum_{\substack{   k \in \mathbb{N} \text{ square-free}, \\ \text{the primes of } k \\ \subseteq \{p_1, \ldots, p_m \}, \\ \text{with $p_m$ included}    }} \frac{\mu(k)}{k^s}, \hspace{2em} \forall m \geq 1
$$

ie. in the Venn diagram the sets of indices of the $S^{(m)}$ are non-overlapping concentric rings :

[image]

Or formally if $t > r$, $S^{(t)} = Z_t \setminus Z_{t - 1}$, and $S^{(r)} \subseteq Z_r \subseteq Z_{t - 1} \therefore S^{(r)} \cap S^{(t)} = \varnothing$, ie. the $S^{(r)}$ are mutually disjoint.

Now taking a square-free index $n \in \mathbb{N}$ in series $S$ of equation (\ref{eq:dirichlet}), $n$ is a product of primes (not necessarily consecutive primes) and taking $m$ sufficiently large $n$ must appear as an index in the finite summation $Z_m$ of equation (\ref{eq:Zm}). Then there is a least such $m \geq 0$. If $m = 0$, then $n$ (as an index) $\in S^{(0)}$, and $n = 1$ in this case, otherwise $n$ (as an index) $\in Z_m \setminus Z_{m - 1} = S^{(m)}$.

Thus the mutually disjoint sets of indices of the finite sub-series $S^{(r)} (r \geq 0)$ of $S$ form a partition of the set of all indices of series $S$ of equation (\ref{eq:dirichlet}). Then in the sense of [1, p142, Theorem 4] or Theorem 1 in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4576608/417024) to [Rearrangements of absolutely convergent series](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/414130/417024), $\{S^{(r)} : r \geq 0 \}$ is a rearrangement of series $S$ in the extended sense, so that since $S$ is absolutely convergent, we have :

\begin{equation}
S = \sum_{r = 0}^{\infty} S^{(r)} \label{eq:partition} \tag{5}
\end{equation}

with the convergence absolute. But the sums of the sub-series $S^{(r)}$ are :
$$
S^{(0)} = Z_0, S^{(1)} = Z_1 - Z_0, \; \ldots, \; S^{(r + 1)} = Z_{r + 1} - Z_r,
$$
therefore the $m$<sup>th</sup> partial sum of $S$ in equation (\ref{eq:partition}) is :

$$
S^{(0)} + S^{(1)} + \cdots + S^{(m)} = Z_0 + (Z_1 - Z_0) + \cdots + (Z_m - Z_{m - 1}) = Z_m
$$

Thus :
\begin{eqnarray*}
S & = & \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} Z_m \\
& = & \frac{1}{\zeta(s)} \hspace{3em} \mbox{from equation (\ref{eq:limZm})} .
\end{eqnarray*}

**References**

[1] Konrad Knopp (1954), Theory and Application of Infinite Series, 2nd English Edition translated from 4th German Edition, Blackie & Sons.